# a secure way of doing something in a web app

Tags: web-applications, security

In a hacking challenge I've found something like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1500" name="price">
```

if you are smart enough to change the value (which is imposed by the client-side of the web application)..you can change the price of the item.
I was wondering..how can I make that line of code more secure? I guess you should impose the price by the server-side as a start..any suggestions on how to deal with such a issue is very welcome..thanks a lot..

Comment: Remeber, secure client storage, is no client storage...

Answer (score 0):

Don't include it client-side. Why should the price be client-side, other than to display to the user in the first place?  (Actually, there's no harm in having the price available on the client... You'd want your customers to see the price, but it would be foolish to actually ***trust*** that the price is accurate, and hasn't been tampered with.

When processing an item in an order, you should look up the price based on the ItemId, not accepting the price from the client.  Any client side data is automatically considered untrusted, and should be validated.  In context, assuming this is an item and you're clicking an "Add To Cart" option, it would be just foolish to accept that the hidden field value is the right price.  ***Validating it would mean, in this case, not only ensuring it's a decimal number, but the actual price.***

Instead, the item should have an ID, and the call on the server side would use that ID to look up the price in a Products table, and use the verified price, retrieved from the Products table.

Even if you were to encrypt the price, you'd have to assume it has been tampered with.  This is one of those obvious cases where security and common sense should be implemented in the initial design stage. If it were, things like that wouldn't make it into code in the first place.

---

All of that said, there might be a legitimate business reason for having it there that has nothing to do with the ordering process.  Perhaps the development team WANTS to have it exposed via a hidden field.  If they wanted the price to be readable via javascript or something, it would make sense to have it available... Maybe for a client-side function that adjusts it when the Qty is changed, for example.  I'm not sure I'd do it that way, but in that scenario, there's no harm in it.

Comment: I perfectly agree with you..it is basically what I was thinking about it but your answer is by far better exaplained (:

Thanks for the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Typically you show the price on the web page so the user can tell how much they are paying but the final determination of the price is still from the database of prices on the server.

If you have a lot of price changing going on, you can make it so the user is notified if the price changes between them viewing it and them clicking to buy.

If the definitive price is contained in the web page, its just inviting folks to set their own price. If you are going to do that, you might as well advertise and get the extra business such a feature would imply.

If you are the hacker, I suggest you put on your white hat and email the owners of the site to let them know they have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a version of this hack where the price is set to a negative number; when the cart is totalled that means the hacker can get free stuff.

For example if the page lets you set a price for a TV of -£5,000 then I could add goods for say £5,001 to my cart and only pay your site £1

It doesn't help solve your problem, but as the other posts here have said, you really shouldn't be trusting the prices that come from your web page. When you calculate any prices you should get the values from your product database, hopefully there are no products in there with a price of -£5,000...

Comment: I wouldn't even thought that such a vulnerability existed in real case scenarios..  
@SimonMartin that is pretty brilliant (:    
how would you classify this vulnerability btw?

Comment: Can't remember; but check out http://blog.whitehatsec.com/root-of-the-issue/ as it explains a related hack. Essentially trust _nothing_ from your users, **always** validate server side and even then you may still need to apply some logic to make sure you're not being exploited. There is no silver bullet, you need security like an onion... in layers